# Security Protocolos - .Net Core/IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

I need to add the follow security protocolos in my .net core API:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self';
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.mywebsite.com
```

First question: Is it correct? I added this code in my startup file.

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'none';frame-ancestors 'self';frame-ancestors 'self' *.mywebsite.com");
```

Second question: Also added the following security protocols in my API web.config file, do I need to add in my Angular(application that consumes the API) web.config file too?`

```
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
<add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
<add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';" />
<add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
<add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />
```

Comment: For the first question: that piece of code alone is not enough for us to know where it's being executed.

Comment: "_First question: Is it correct? I added this code in my startup file._" - You tell us; did it work?

Comment: What's your ultimate aim on adding "security", could you pls explain it? Thanks for your response in advance.